# How to count occurrences of a given frequency in a spectrogram

Tags: python, audio, spectrogram

I have a spectrogram like this and I would like to sum up all the occurrences of a given frequency:

[image]

I tried to outline the questions that finally have no sense. I apologize for that.

Well the picture shows the information in dB of a wav file, that I load. The picture is the result of specgram method.

As far as I know I can see 4 main features during the time starting from 0.8 sec. in 7k Hz, 4.5 kz, 2.5 kz, 900 hz . Well, it looks like it maintains during the time so I want to add all this occurrences

My source code right now, is something like this. You can see that I get some freq information but this is not corresponding with the graphic values (in the intervals 7k Hz, 4.5 kz, 2.5 kz, 900 hz )

```
for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK_SIZE * RECORD_SECONDS)):
  # little endian, signed shortdata_chunk
  data_chunk = array('h', stream.read(CHUNK_SIZE))
  if byteorder == 'big':
data_chunk.byteswap()
  data_all.extend(data_chunk)


# Take the fft and square each value
fftData=abs(np.fft.rfft(data_chunk))**2

# find the maximum
which = fftData[1:].argmax() + 1

# use quadratic interpolation around the max
if which != len(fftData)-1:
print "which %f and %f." % (which,which)
y0,y1,y2 = np.log(fftData[which-1:which+2:])
x1 = (y2 - y0) * .5 / (2 * y1 - y2 - y0)
# find the frequency and output it

#==   THIS IS NOT the real freq ======================================
#==   How can I get the values of the freq ???========================
thefreq = (which+x1)*RATE/CHUNK_SIZE
print "The freq is %f Hz. and %d" % (thefreq,int(thefreq) )
else:
thefreq = which*RATE/CHUNK_SIZE
print "The freq is %f Hz." % (thefreq)


Fs = 16000
f = np.arange(1, 9) * 2000
t = np.arange(RECORD_SECONDS * Fs) / Fs 
x = np.empty(t.shape)
for i in range(8):
x[i*Fs:(i+1)*Fs] = np.cos(2*np.pi * f[i] * t[i*Fs:(i+1)*Fs])

w = np.hamming(512)
Pxx, freqs, bins = mlab.specgram(data_all, NFFT=512, Fs=Fs, window=w, 
                noverlap=464)


#plot the spectrogram in dB
Pxx_dB = np.log10(Pxx)
pyplot.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.4)

pyplot.subplot(311)
ex1 = bins[0], bins[-1], freqs[0], freqs[-1]
pyplot.imshow(np.flipud(Pxx_dB), extent=ex1)
#pyplot.axis('auto')
pyplot.axis('tight')
pyplot.xlabel('time (s)')
pyplot.ylabel('freq (Hz)')


#==   EXTRA LOG                    ======================================

print ("The max number is  >>>>>", np.max(Pxx), " - ",  np.max(bins))
Pxx_dB = np.log10(Pxx)
print ("The max number is  >>>>>", np.max(Pxx_dB))


np.savetxt("./tmp__PXX", Pxx, fmt = '%f')
np.savetxt("./tmp__PXX_dB", Pxx_dB, fmt = '%f')



pyplot.show()
```

I would like to do something like this [image] that you can find in this other question 
[Removing specific frequencies between a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21518512/python-removing-specific-frequencies-between-a-range), The thing is how can I count all these frequencies.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: What about: http://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.specgram

Comment: i don't understand what kind of answer you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Using the answer from this question in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22814128/how-do-i-get-the-values-of-a-specific-frequency-range?answertab=votes#tab-top) and dumping to a simple matrix, I solved the problem, thank you very much for your help